Your Average Character
Write a program or function that takes in a string of characters, and finds the alphabetical average:
That is, the average of the alphabetical positions (numerically) of each letter converted to lowercase (excluding other characters), rounded to the nearest integer, then converted back to its letter equivalent:
Here is an example:
The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog -> m

The alphabetical indexes are:
20 8 5 17 21 9 3 11 6 15 24 10 21 13 16 19 15 22 5 18 20 8 5 12 1 26 25 4 15 7

The average is 13.366666667, so rounded, it would be 13
The letter with an alphabetical index of 13 is "m"

Additional Rules

Standard Loopholes are forbidden
You can only output a single lowercase letter.
You can return undefined, an error, or an equivalent when encountering empty inputs or any inputs without letters.
When rounding a number directly between two integers, you are to round upwards. (e.g. 1.5 -> 2, 3.5 -> 4)

Test Cases
The quick fox jups over the lazy dog -> m
a -> a
aaaaa -> a
abcde -> c
bcde -> d
a1!b2@c -> b
ABCde -> c
POP -> p
A B C -> b
@@@@ -> (undefined or error)
-> (undefined or error)

This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Can I return @ when given @@@@?

If the average is exactly halfway between two integers, how should it be rounded?

@Tbw I think this is covered by "undefined".

Suggested test case: The quick fox jups over the lazy dog → m, the point being that the letter that corresponds with the alphabetical average isn't necessarily present in the input.

@m90 In standard mathematics, 1.5 is rounded to 2, and so do most programming languages, so you should round upwards.

@Jake Actually many programming languages round half to even (C#, VB.NET, Python, Rust, R)

Could we instead convert to uppercase and return the uppercase average?

@Jordan yes, as long as the output is in lowercase

Is 0 considered a valid output for empty inputs or any inputs without letters?

The question should define explicitly which letters are considered alphabetical, and in which order.  And also how the mapping to lowercase is done (for example, does I become ı or i?)

C (gcc), 70 bytes
c,t;f(int*s){for(t=c=0;*s;s++)isalpha(*s)?t+=*s|32,c++:0;c=1.*t/c+.5;}

Try it online!

Vyxal, 49 bitsv2, 6.125 bytes
ǍøAṁṙøA

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
1101010010111100011000100000010011100010000101010

Very literal implementation of the question.
Explained
ǍøAṁṙøA­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Ǎ        # ‎⁡Remove characters from the input that aren't letters
 øA      # ‎⁢Get the 1-based alphabet index of each letter
   ṁ     # ‎⁣Average those indices
    ṙ    # ‎⁤Round to the nearest integer
     øA  # ‎⁢⁡And convert that back to a letter using the result as a 1-based index


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Go, 163 137 bytes
import."unicode"
func f(s string)(o rune){for _,r:=range s{if IsLetter(r){o+=r|32-'a'}}
return rune(.5+(float64(o)/float64(len(s))+'a'))}

Attempt This Online!

-26 by not using math, and OR-ing with 32 to lowercase it (lowercase letters have bit 5 (0-indexed) set)


Arturo, 68 bytes
$=>[to :char round average to[:integer]to[:char]match lower&{[a-z]}]

Try it!

R, 67 63 bytes
Edit: -4 bytes thanks to @jdt.
\(s)intToUtf8(.5+mean(utf8ToInt(gsub("[^a-z]","",tolower(s)))))

Attempt This Online!

\(s)intToUtf8(.5+mean(utf8ToInt(gsub("[^a-z]","",tolower(s)))))

This works because if you feed a real number into intToUtf8 it will apply the floor function first to get an integer and then convert the integer (as opposed to say rounding or throwing an error for an invalid input).

Python 3, 98 96 95 bytes
lambda s:chr(round(sum(ord(c)-96 for c in s.lower()if c.isalpha())/sum(map(str.isalpha,s)))+96)

Try it online!

Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Here's 76 bytes with some rearrangements. Specifically, you don't need the -96/+96, and you can reuse the list to get the number of alphabetical characters.

TIO - one more byte on top of emanresu A's by using %32 to get the location of an alphabetic character and adding 96 to to result to get us back to the ordinal needed.

...actually we can bitwise OR with 32 to take any uppercase ordinal to its lowercase counterpart, so 72 bytes :)

APL+WIN, 62 bytes
Prompts for string. Fails on domain error if the string does not contain any valid characters.
n[⌊.5+(÷⍴l)×+/l←(((n←⎕av[17+⍳26])⍳s)~27),(⎕av[65+⍳26]⍳s←⎕)~27]

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

05AB1E, 10 bytes
ADIlákÅAòè

Input as a list of characters.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
A          # Push the lowercase alphabet
 D         # Duplicate it
  I        # Push the input character-list
   l       # Convert it to lowercase
    á      # Only keep the letters, removing any other character
     k     # Get the 0-based index of each letter in the alphabet
      ÅA   # Take the average of this list
        ò  # Round it to the nearest integer
         è # 0-based index that into the alphabet
           # (after which the letter is output implicitly as result)

Minor note: it doesn't matter that 05AB1E uses 0-based indexing instead of 1-based as the challenge description, since it just means the entire average is decreased by exactly 1 after taking the average, saving an > after the k and < before the è.

Uiua, 16 bytes
+@a⁅÷⧻⟜/+-@A▽⊸±⌵

Try it online!
Explanation
+@a⁅÷⧻⟜/+-@A▽⊸±⌵

               ⌵ # To uppercase
            ▽⊸±  # Keep alphabetic
         -@A     # convert to alphabetic position (A: 0, B: 1, ..)
    ÷⧻⟜/+        # mean
+@a⁅             # round, convert to lowercase letter


Zsh, 61 bytes
set ${(Ls::)1//[^A-Za-z]};for x;$[t+=#x];jot -c 1 $[t/$#.+.5]

Try it online!
Throws lots of errors because $[t+=#x] should be ((t+=#x)) but that's an extra byte.

Java (JDK), 91 85 83 bytes
s->(char)(s.toLowerCase().chars().filter(c->c>96&c<123).average().orElseThrow()+.5)

-6 for rounding thanks to jdt
Try it online!

You can add 0.5 instead of using Math.round. I also don't think orElseThrow is needed.

TIO

I didn't consider the rounding thanks, but shouldn't empty inputs throw an exception? You can return undefined, an error, or an equivalent when encountering empty inputs or any inputs without letters. I don't know if an equivalent also includes 0

I think retuning 0 is valid for empty cases.

Suggest c>96&c<123 instead of c>96&&c<123

JavaScript (Node.js), 78 77 bytes
x=>([...x,w=n=0].map(c=>w+=(d=parseInt(c,36))>9&&++n&&d)|w/n+.5).toString(36)

Try it online!

I tried x=>(w=n=0,x.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>w+=parseInt(c,36,++n)),w/n+.5|0).toString(36) but it's still 78 bytes...

@Neil x=>(w=n=0,x.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>w+=parseInt(c,36,++n)+.5)|w/n).toString(36) passes all test but fail some other cases

Vyxal 3, 7 bytes
ȦøA∆AøA

Vyxal It Online!
why does vyxal 3 not have a round element??? oh well
edit: apparently the letter to number auto-rounds but we still dont have a round element.

oddly symmetrical, i like it

Google Sheets, 82 bytes 102 bytes
=char(0.5+average(sort(code(split(regexreplace(lower(A1),"([a-z])|.","$19"),9)))))

Put the text string in cell A1 and the formula in B1.
Uses sort() as an array enabler only. Signals undefined with 9 and error with #VALUE!.

The char() function always rounds down, hence 0.5.

Ruby, 69 bytes
->s{t=n=0.0
s.downcase.scan(/[a-z]/){t+=_1.ord;n+=1}
(t/n).round.chr}

Attempt This Online!

55 bytes

@Dingus Very nice. You should go ahead and post your own answer.

Retina 0.8.2, 62 bytes
T`Llp`ll_
^(.)\1+$
$1
T`@l`l@`^.
T`l@`@l`.$
}O`.
+r`.(.+).?
$1

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
T`Llp`ll_

Lowercase letters and discard anything else.
^(.)\1+$
$1

If all the letters are the same, then just keep one.
T`@l`l@`^.

Increment the first letter.
T`l@`@l`.$

Decrement the last letter.
O`.

Sort the letters (back) into order.
}`

Repeat until the buffer stabilises, which happens either when there is one letter or the buffer only contains copies of two consecutive letters.
+r`.(.+).?
$1

Keep only the middle letter.

APL (Dyalog Extended), 24 bytes
(⌊⎕A⊃⍨∘⌊.5++⌿÷≢)27~⍨⎕A⍳⌈

⌈ uppercase
⎕A⍳ one-based indices in uppercase Alphabet (not found → 27)
27~⍨  remove 27s
(…) apply the following tacit function to that:
  ≢ the tally (length)
  ÷ divides
  +⌿ the sum
  .5+ added to one half
  ∘⌊ rounded down, then…
  ⎕A⊃⍨ pick that element from the uppercase Alphabet
  ⌊ lowercase
Try it online!

Factor, 47 bytes
[ >lower 97 ..= 122 within mean round 1string ]

Try it online in an old version of Factor for +1 byte

Raku, 47 bytes
Attempt This Online!
(.sum/$_).round.chr with .lc.comb(/<:L>/)>>.ord


Lowercase the input and then "comb" the letters in it, i.e., select those with the Unicode property L
Now we have a Sequence of characters -- map them to their ordinals with >>.ord (which is the same as .map(&ord) here but shorter)
Topicalize these Seq of ordinals with with (given also works and more idiomatic since with cares about definedness, but it's 1 character shorter :)
Lastly get the mean, round it and query the corresponding character


JavaScript (Node.js), 75 bytes
s=>(B=Buffer)([s.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>t+=B(c)[0&n++]|32,t=n=0)&&t/n+.5])+""

Try it online!
Commented
s =>           // s = input string
(B = Buffer)([ // B = alias for Buffer
  s.replace(   //   replace in s ...
    /[a-z]/gi, //   ... all letters, case insensitive
    c =>       //   for each letter c:
    t += B(c)[ //     add to t the ASCII code of c
      0 & n++  //     and increment n
    ] | 32,    //     force the code to lower case
    t = n = 0  //     start with t = 0 and n = 0
  ) &&         //   end of replace()
  t / n + .5   //   compute the rounded average t / n
])             // end of Buffer()
+ ""           // coerce to a string


jq -Rr, 70 67 bytes
ascii_downcase|[scan("[a-z]")|explode[]]|add/length|[round]|implode

Demo

Charcoal, 20 bytes
≔Φ↧Ｓ№βιθ℅⁺·⁵∕ΣＥθ℅ιＬθ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
≔Φ↧Ｓ№βιθ

Get the letters of the input and lowercase them.
℅⁺·⁵∕ΣＥθ℅ιＬθ

Take the average, rounded.

Japt v2.0a0, 16 bytes
v f\l
xc ÷UÊ r d

Try it
v f\l\nxc ÷UÊ r d     :Implicit input of string U
v                     :Lowercase
  f                   :Match
   \l                 :  /[a-z]/g
     \n               :Reassign to U
       x              :Sum of
        c             :  Character codes
          ÷           :Divided by
           UÊ         :  Length of U
              r       :Round
                d     :Character at that codepoint


Perl 5, 47 bytes
sub{@_=map ord,lc(pop)=~/[a-z]/g;chr.5+&sum/@_}

Try it online!

Mathematica, 38 bytes
FromCharacterCode@Mean@ToCharacterCode

Try it online!

C#, 77 bytes
char F(string i)=>(char)i.ToLower().Where(x=>x>96&x<123).Average(x=>x+.5);

Try it online!
Explanation
char F(string i) => (char) // Cast the result to a char
    i.ToLower() // Lower-case the chars in the string
        .Where(x=> x>96 & x<123) // Ensure the character is valid
        .Average(x=> x+0.5); // Average the characters (and add 0.5 to round up)


Haskell, 104 bytes
f x|l<-[c#64|c<-toEnum.fromEnum<$>x,let n#l=n+sum[32|l<c,c-l<27],0<0#64#96]=toEnum.round$sum l/sum(1<$l)

Surprisingly Double is an instance of Enum.
Try it online!

Racket, 101 bytes
(λ(s[a(regexp-replace*"[^a-zA-Z]"s"")])(round(/(for/sum([c a])(bitwise-ior 32 c))(bytes-length a))))

Try it online!
Takes input as a byte string and returns an ASCII integer. (Sadly verbose) |32 trick taken from this comment. Rounds .5 to even, which is technically noncompliant, but oh well.
This is my first answer in over two years and my first Racket answer ever, so let me know if there's anything amiss.
Character output (113 bytes):
(λ(s[a(regexp-replace*"[^a-zA-Z]"s"")])(write-byte(round(/(for/sum([c a])(bitwise-ior 32 c)))(bytes-length a))))

Try it online!

APL, 32 30 29 chars
⎕UCS⌊(+/÷≢)⎕UCS⎕A(⊣(/⍨)∊)⍥⎕C⍨

Explanation
⎕UCS⌊(+/÷≢)⎕UCS⎕A(⊣(/⍨)∊)⍥⎕C⍨
               ⎕A           ⍨   ⍝ Take the alphabet on the right and input on the left
                 (      )⍥⎕C    ⍝ Call `lowercase` on each arg before calling new inner train
                   (/⍨)         ⍝ Explode the
                  ⊢             ⍝   input string (right arg)
                       ∊        ⍝   by elements in the left arg
           ⎕UCS                 ⍝ Convert to numbers
     (    )                     ⍝ Find average (choo choo!):
        ÷                       ⍝   divide
      +/                        ⍝   the sum
         ≢                      ⍝   by the tally (count)
    ⌊                           ⍝ Floor
⎕UCS                            ⍝ Convert back to letter


AWK, 92 bytes
@load "ordchr";BEGIN{FS=X}{gsub(" ",X);for($0=tolower($0);++i<=NF;)x+=ord($i);$0=chr(x/NF)}1

Try it online!
`
@load "ordchr";              # character manipulation module
BEGIN{FS=X}                  # split every character
{gsub(" ",X);                # remove spaces
for($0=tolower($0);++i<=NF;) # make it lowercase
x+=ord($i);                  # total it up
$0=chr(x/NF)}1               # average and print 

Awk's default rounding should do the trick, but ymmv.
